# Div layout using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Div layout using Javascript

If i click on + it should be open and it again click on - it should be close it is working fine but what i need to is that if there are more div how to handle them on run time.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
#widnow{
width:100%;
border:solid 1px;
    float:left;
}

#title_bar{
background: #FEFEFE;
height: 25px;
width: 100%;
}
#button{
border:solid 1px;
width: 25px;
height: 23px;
float:right;
cursor:pointer;
}
.box{
height: 50%;
 width: 50%;
background: #DFDFDF;
float:left;
}
#title_bar1{
background: #FEFEFE;
height: 25px;
width: 100%;
}
#button1{
border:solid 1px;
width: 25px;
height: 23px;
float:right;
cursor:pointer;
}
.box1{
height: 50%;
width: 50%;
background:#C0C0C0;
float:left;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="widnow">

<div class="box" >
<div id="title_bar">

        <div id="button">+</div>
</div>
</div>
<div  class="box1">
    <div id="title_bar1">
            <div id="button1">-</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

script.js

```
  jQuery().ready(function() {

$("#button").click(function(){
if($(this).html() == "-"){
    $(this).html("+");
    $( ".box" ).css( "width","50%" );
    $( ".box1" ).show();

}
else{
    $(this).html("-");
    $( ".box" ).css( "width","100%" );
     $( ".box1" ).hide();
}

});


        });
```

Please come with idea that can help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use relative paths/ e.g.

```
$(this).parent().css("width","50%");
```

So you always style the box that contains the (+/-) element that has been clicked.

You'll need to adapt your $(".box1") showing/hiding code, too; and as Pulkit said - you should use classes instead of ids. (select the child with the class ("box1") beneath the parent is:

```
$(this).parent().children("#box1")
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't hardcode the selector of the divs. This way you can expand it beyond a single div.

Use something like this:

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    $(this).parent('div').css({'width' : '50%'});
});
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xk34w/11/)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving a different id to each div element and also give the class and perform the jQuery function with id (#) instead of class (.)

Comment: how can i give id using javascript