# How can have a div which contain multiple multiple div it may 4-6-8 how can i fit them on page load using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can have a div which contain multiple multiple div it may 4-6-8 how can i fit them on page load using Jquery.

```
<div id="main">
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

I want to create a jquery function which can fit child div to parent div by arresting their height and width on page load.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking, be more specific please. Is the HTML in the question what you already have when your page loads, or an example of what you'd want to end up with?

Comment: @jackJoe According to Wiktionary: "(archaic) Second-person singular simple present form of urge". I think they may have meant to say "insert", but I can only guess.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist i've read that on Wiktionary too, sounds that this is a historic question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to take a stab, and hope that what I *think* you want is what you *actually* want. I assume you want to insert a dynamic number of `<div class="box">` elements into the `<div id="main">` element when the page has loaded. If that is the case, this should work:

HTML

```
<div id="main"></div>
```

jQuery

```
function createBoxes(numberOfBoxes) {
    var $box = $('<div/>').addClass('box');
    var $container = $('#main');
    for(var i = 1; i <= numberOfBoxes; i++) {
        $container.append($box.clone().text(i));   
    }
}

$(function() { // calls createBoxes() when the DOM is ready
               // shortened version of $(document).ready(function() {
    createBoxes(4);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zQ4We/)

Comment: how can i get id for child show can i perform operation on that.

Comment: Make it little bit more clear i want to just add new child div to my html code and do not want to worry other thing it should be just set all child div height and width.

Comment: please consider this also..
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027655/div-layout-using-javascript